# Android XML designer does not match the actual screen / Icons and images not showing

Tags: android, xml, android-studio

So, it is pretty clear that the android xml designer helps put everything on its position so that it stays there when we actually use the app. Well, not for me. I get all objects on its place, constraint everything, scale everything and yet, it looks broken on my device/avd with the same dimensions of my device. Might as well ask about images and icons not rendering in the views for some reason, even when the drawables get set on the java class. Started doing that some days ago and couldn't find anything either.

[image: Here we can see how it should look]

[image: Here's how it's actually showing]

I haven't really found anything on it, so I was hoping that somebody could show me how to actually make it match.

If needed, this is the xml for the activity:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/ConstraintLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:background="@drawable/usuarioanadir"
    tools:context=".UserAddScreen">


    <Button
        android:id="@+id/gotoBack"
        style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Button.Borderless"
        android:layout_width="57dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="24dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="24dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="28dp"
        android:alpha="1"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:onClick="gotoBack"
        android:rotationX="0"
        android:scaleX="1"
        android:textColor="#00FFFFFF"
        android:textColorHighlight="#00FFFFFF"
        android:textColorHint="#00FFFFFF"
        android:textColorLink="#00FFFFFF"
        android:visibility="visible"
        app:backgroundTint="#00FFFFFF"
        app:backgroundTintMode="multiply"
        app:icon="?attr/actionModeCloseDrawable"
        app:iconPadding="0dp"
        app:iconSize="50dp"
        app:iconTint="#FF0000"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:rippleColor="#00FFFFFF" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/AddSurname"
        android:layout_width="343dp"
        android:layout_height="55dp"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="false"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="false"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="false"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="false"
        android:layout_centerInParent="false"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="false"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_marginStart="176dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="176dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="44dp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:fontFamily="@font/segoeuiz"
        android:gravity="end"
        android:hapticFeedbackEnabled="false"
        android:hint="Apellidos"
        android:inputType="textPersonName"
        android:textColor="@color/verde_junta"
        android:textColorHint="@color/verde_junta"
        android:textSize="24sp"
        android:translationX="0dp"
        android:translationY="0dp"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/AddUsername" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/SelectImage"
        android:layout_width="194dp"
        android:layout_height="195dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="24dp"
        android:onClick="selectImageAction"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/gotoBack"
        tools:srcCompat="@tools:sample/avatars" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/AddUsername"
        android:layout_width="346dp"
        android:layout_height="58dp"
        android:layout_centerInParent="false"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="false"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="44dp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:fontFamily="@font/segoeuiz"
        android:gravity="end"
        android:hapticFeedbackEnabled="false"
        android:hint="Nombre"
        android:inputType="textPersonName"
        android:textColor="@color/verde_junta"
        android:textColorHint="@color/verde_junta"
        android:textSize="24sp"
        android:translationX="0dp"
        android:translationY="0dp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.912"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/SelectImage" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/AddAge"
        android:layout_width="66dp"
        android:layout_height="47dp"
        android:layout_centerInParent="false"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="false"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_marginStart="330dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="330dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="60dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:fontFamily="@font/segoeuiz"
        android:gravity="clip_horizontal|clip_vertical|right"
        android:hint="69"
        android:inputType="number"
        android:numeric="integer"
        android:textColor="@color/verde_junta"
        android:textColorHint="@color/verde_junta"
        android:textSize="24sp"
        android:translationX="0dp"
        android:translationY="0dp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.835"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/AddSurname" />

    <Spinner
        android:id="@+id/AddGender"
        android:layout_width="112dp"
        android:layout_height="31dp"
        android:layout_centerInParent="false"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="false"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_marginStart="291dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="291dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="56dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        android:gravity="clip_horizontal|clip_vertical|right"
        android:translationX="0dp"
        android:translationY="0dp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.875"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/AddAge" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/AddRoomNumber"
        android:layout_width="53dp"
        android:layout_height="53dp"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="false"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="false"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="false"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="false"
        android:layout_centerInParent="false"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="false"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="72dp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:fontFamily="@font/segoeuiz"
        android:hint="69"
        android:inputType="number"
        android:numeric="integer"
        android:textColor="@color/verde_junta"
        android:textColorHint="@color/verde_junta"
        android:textSize="24sp"
        android:translationX="0dp"
        android:translationY="0dp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.924"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/AddGender" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/AddObservation"
        style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Button.Borderless"
        android:layout_width="47dp"
        android:layout_height="45dp"
        android:layout_centerInParent="false"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="false"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_marginStart="450dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="450dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="50dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="50dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="176dp"
        android:alpha="1"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:gravity="clip_horizontal|clip_vertical|right"
        android:onClick="addObservation"
        android:textColor="#00FFFFFF"
        android:textColorHighlight="#00FFFFFF"
        android:textColorHint="#00FFFFFF"
        android:textColorLink="#00FFFFFF"
        android:translationX="0dp"
        android:translationY="0dp"
        android:visibility="visible"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.944"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/AddPathologies"
        style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Button.Borderless"
        android:layout_width="51dp"
        android:layout_height="47dp"
        android:layout_centerInParent="false"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="false"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_marginStart="450dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="450dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="51dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="51dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="64dp"
        android:alpha="1"
        android:backgroundTint="#00FFFFFF"
        android:backgroundTintMode="multiply"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:gravity="clip_horizontal|clip_vertical|right"
        android:onClick="addPathology"
        android:textColor="#00FFFFFF"
        android:textColorHighlight="#00FFFFFF"
        android:textColorHint="#00FFFFFF"
        android:textColorLink="#00FFFFFF"
        android:translationX="0dp"
        android:translationY="0dp"
        android:visibility="visible"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/AddObservation"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="1.0"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/SaveUser"
        style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Button.Borderless"
        android:layout_width="66dp"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="false"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="false"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="false"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="false"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:layout_marginStart="450dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="450dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="68dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="24dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="24dp"
        android:alpha="1"
        android:backgroundTint="#00FFFFFF"
        android:backgroundTintMode="multiply"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:gravity="clip_horizontal|clip_vertical|right"
        android:icon="@android:drawable/ic_menu_save"
        android:iconTint="#FF0000"
        android:onClick="saveUser"
        android:textColor="#00FFFFFF"
        android:textColorHighlight="#00FFFFFF"
        android:textColorHint="#00FFFFFF"
        android:textColorLink="#00FFFFFF"
        android:translationX="0dp"
        android:translationY="0dp"
        android:visibility="visible"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="1.0"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/AddObservation" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: android:layout_width="343dp" measures like that are bad practice and they are the reason that you are getting those results, you are not using the ConstraintLayout properly

Comment: Then how am I supposed to fit the stuff where it belongs?

Comment: use Linear Layout to balance the layout. when you define a value like 343dp it will be a constant value across all devices with different dpi. so if you designer is a 720p layout with 250dpi, it will be different on an actual device with 1080p screen and 400dpi.